# Запуск dll .NET 5 из своего кода

Tags: c#, .net-core

Хочу запустить dll написанную .NET 5 из своего кода тоже на .NET 5.

Если взять консольное приложение то все работает, я его запускаю.
Вот код

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"ConsoleApp2.dll");
Console.WriteLine(asm.FullName);
Type t = asm.GetType("ConsoleApp2.Program", true, true);
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod("Main", BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
object result = method.Invoke(obj, new object[] { new string[] { } });
```

Берем тот же код и запускаем winform dll, меняем только название dll.
winform dll это обычный новый проект без изменений.
Я тестирую. Мне нужно будет запускать разные dll при необходимости.

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"WindowsFormsApp1.dll");
Type t = asm.GetType("WindowsFormsApp1.Program", true, true);
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod("Main", BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
object result = method.Invoke(obj, new object[] { new string[] { } });
```

Получаем ошибку

```
Unhandled exception. System.MissingMethodException: Cannot create an abstract class.
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& hasNoDefaultCtor)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtorSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at ConsoleApp3.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\VSproject\ConsoleApp3\ConsoleApp3\Program.cs:line 13
```

Ошибка в этой строчке

```
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

На ней вылет.

код WindowsFormsApp1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Что я не так делаю?

StackTrace

```
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at ConsoleApp3.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\VSproject\ConsoleApp3\ConsoleApp3\Program.cs:line 21
```

Comment: Покажите исходный код класса `Program` Winforms приложения.

Comment: @aepot  добавил в пост. Это пустой новый проект WinForms

Comment: Здесь нет `string[] args`.

Comment: @aepot мы до нее даже не доходим еще. Вылетаем на этой строчке ```object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);```

Comment: `static class Program` - у вас статический класс в WinForms.

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду, говоря "net core 5"? Это новая платформа .NET 5 (без слова core)?

Comment: @Alexander Petrov да.  Это 5ка новая.  привычка еще core называть

Comment: Гуевое приложение нужно обязательно запускать в потоке с установленным `ApartmentState.STA`. Вон на методе `Main` стоит атрибут `[STAThread]`.

Comment: Вы какую конечную цель преследуете? Если хотите запускать другое _приложение_ из своего кода, то нужно делать это с помощью класса `Process`. А если хотите вызывать какие-то методы из библиотеки, то библиотека должна быть рассчитана на это. Этот метод не должен быть точкой запуска приложения.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov цель такая. Есть приложение. Считывает с нужного места xml файл в котором указана нужная dll. Мое приложение ее запускает. Dll делает что нужно завершается. какая dll будет в этот момент неизвестно. Считывается с сервера. Их(dll) много. В данный момент нужно просто стартануть dll без exe файла для этой dll в net5.

Comment: _какая dll будет в этот момент неизвестно_ - ok, dll форматирует диск, сливает ваши данные, ставит дикпик...

Comment: Судя по тому, что в обоих случаях вы явно вызывает метод `Main`, который является точкой старта приложжения, нужно использовать [Process.Start](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: @Alexander Petrov  не совсем так. Это будем некий локальный магазин приложений для предприятия. так как net5 компилирует приложения в exe и dll файл. В котором dll сама программа а exe только запускалка. Я хочу написать свою запускалку всех dll И магазин приложений обновляет только нужные мне dll И запускает их. Я понимаю что я могу написать аля свой стим.  И запускать по человечски exe модули. Но мне было бы удобней перебрасывать только dll.

Comment: _магазин приложений_ - то есть у вас именно _приложения_. Значит используйте Process.Start.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov хм.. я просто не подумал про то, что можно dll просто запустить командой. Спасибо. Но Ваш код тоже пригодится. Если понадобится читать методы из dll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В приложении WinForms у вас статический класс - невозможно создать его экземпляр.

Получив тип:

```
Type t = asm.GetType("...", true, true);
```

проверьте, абстрактный (статический) он или нет. И далее либо создаёте его экземпляр, либо сразу вызываете нужный метод.

```
MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod("Main", BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

if (t.IsAbstract)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Static");
    object result = method.Invoke(null, new object[] { new string[] { } });
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Instance");
    object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    object result = method.Invoke(obj, new object[] { new string[] { } });
}
```

Comment: Пока всеравно не могу запустить, выдает ошибку Ваш Static,
Unhandled exception. System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Определяется как static  и ругается уже  на строку bject result = method.Invoke(null, new object[] { new string[] { } });  При этом в winformdll в main я добавил string[] args.

Comment: @Manul74 - Покажите stacktrace исключения. Отредактируйте вопрос, поместив его туда.

Comment: Добавил. это Оно?

Comment: У меня возникла мысль что я не могу вызвать winform dll из консольного приложения. Сделал winform приложение и пытаюсь запустить winform Из DLL получаю ошибку System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: До создания первого объекта IWin32Window в приложении необходимо вызвать SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault.   Он вызывается в dll, Прочитал по инету нужно запустить в новом потоке. Вот тут вопрос как? примера не нашел пока